# Error message when multiplying two columns together

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to create a new column for my data set using pandas that is the product of two columns multiplied together. One set is a value in dollars called price and the other is a number called installs. Running the multiplication code by itself gives me an error 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str''

I tried running the following code to convert the strings into integers.

```
    pd.to_numeric(appdata['Installs'], errors ='ignore')
    pd.to_numeric(appdata['Price'], errors= 'ignore')
    appdata[Income]= appdata['Installs'] * appdata[('Price')]
```

But this gives me the same error.

[image: Error Message]

What other way could I convert my data into integer format?

[image: Data]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have `()` around 'Price'? Also, please post errors/code inside the question itself instead of linking to external images.

Comment: Does your data have the literal `+` as part of the data for `Installs`? If so then your problem is probably because pandas is unable to convert that to a numeric type.

Comment: Please, add the error message in your question as __text__, not image. This way, it can be copied out or searched by future useres of this site.

Comment: You have to assign back the values returned from `pd.to_numeric`

Answer (score 1):

`pd.to_numeric()` does not edit the column in place. You should do:

```
appdata['Installs'] = pd.to_numeric(appdata['Installs'], errors ='ignore')
appdata['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(appdata['Price'], errors= 'ignore')
appdata['Income']= appdata['Installs'] * appdata['Price']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# remove , and + from 'Installs' to make the cells look integer to Pandas
appdata['Installs'] = pd.to_numeric(appdata['Installs'].str.replace(r'[\,\+]+', '', regex=True))
# remove , from 'Price' to make the cells look integer to Pandas
appdata['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(appdata['Price'].str.replace(r'[\,]+', '', regex=True))
# calculate "Income"
appdata['Income'] = appdata['Installs'] * appdata['Price']
```